# HTTP/2 server pushed assets fail to load (HTTP2_CLIENT_REFUSED_STREAM)

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, nginx, cloudflare, http2

I have the following error `ERR_HTTP2_CLIENT_REFUSED_STREAM` in chrome devtools console for all or some of the assets pushed via http2.

[image: ERR_HTTP2_CLIENT_REFUSED_STREAM]

Refreshing the page and clearing the cache randomly fixes this issue partially and sometimes completely.

I am using nginx with http2 enabled (ssl via certbot) and cloudflare.

```
server {
    server_name $HOST;
    root /var/www/$HOST/current/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    set $auth "dev-Server.";

    if ($request_uri ~ ^/opcache-api/.*$){
    set $auth off;
    }

    auth_basic $auth;
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        # Let laravel query strings burst the cache
          expires 1M;
          add_header Cache-Control "public";
        # Or force cache revalidation.
          # add_header Cache-Control "public, no-cache, must-revalidate";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|xml|svg|webp)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires 6M;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:woff|ttf|otf|woff2|eot)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        types     {font/opentype otf;}
        types     {application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot;}
        types     {font/truetype ttf;}
        types     {application/font-woff woff;}
        types     {font/x-woff woff2;}
    }


    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$HOST/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$HOST/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    # include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = $HOST) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name $HOST;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Googling this error doesn't return much results and if it helps, it's a laravel 6 app that pushes those assets, if i disable assets pushing in laravel, then all assets load correctly.

I don't even know where to start looking.

---

### Update 1

I enabled chrome logging, and inspected the logs using Sawbuck, following the instructions provided [here](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) and found that the actual error has some relation with a 414 HTTP response, which implies some caching problem.

[image: log]

---

### Update 2

I found this great [The browser can abort pushed items if it already has them](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/h2-push-tougher-than-i-thought#the-browser-can-abort-pushed-items-if-it-already-has-them) which states the following:

> Chrome will reject pushes if it already has the item in the push cache. It rejects with `PROTOCOL_ERROR` rather than `CANCEL` or `REFUSED_STREAM`.

it also links to some [chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=232040) and [mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1367551) bugs.

Which led me to disable cloudflare completely and test directly with the server, i tried various `Cache-Control` directives and also tried disabling the header, but the same error occures, upon a refresh after a cache clear.

Apparently, chrome cancel the http/2 pushed asset **even when not present in push cache**, leaving the page broken.

**For now, i'm disabling http/2 server push in laravel app as a temporary fix.**

Answer (score 0):

We just got the exact same problem you're describing. We got "net::ERR_HTTP2_CLIENT_REFUSED_STREAM" on one of our Javascript files. Reloading and clearing cache worked but then the problem came back, seemingly randomly. The same issue in Chrome and Edge (Chromium based). Then I tried in Firefox and got the same behavior but Firefox complained that the response for that url was "text/html". My guess is that for some reason we had gotten a "text/html" response cached for that url in Cloudflare. When I opened that url directly in Firefox I got "application/javascript" and then the problem went away. Still not quite sure how this all happened though.

EDIT:
In our case it turned out that the response for a .js file was blocked by the server with a 401 and we didn't send out any cache headers. Cloudflare tries to be helpful because the browser was expecting a .js file so the response was cached even if the status was 401. Which later failed for others because we tried to http2 push a text/html response with status 401 as a .js file. Luckliy Firefox gave us a better, actionable error message.

EDIT2:
Turns out it wasn't a http header cache issue. It was that we had cookie authentication on .js files, and it seems that the http2 push requests doesn't always include cookies. The fix was to allow cookieless requests on the .js files.

Comment: What do you mean with: allow cookieless requests on the .js files? How is that done?

Comment: Our endpoint that serves JS files respond with 401 if a certain cookie isn't set. We simply removed that check.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes here using Symfony's local development server (`symfony server:start`), I could not fix it but this setting (which is the default setting) stops the server to try to push preloaded assets and the error goes away:

`config/packages/dev/webpack_encore.yaml`

```yaml
webpack_encore:
    preload: false
```